# How to read a csv file as series instead of dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to use  `x = pandas.Series.from_csv('File_name.csv', header = None)` 
It throws an error saying IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.

However, If I read it as dataframe and then extract series, it works fine.
`x = pandas.read_csv('File_name.csv', header = None)[0]`

What could be wrong with first method?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Try to add index_col=None parameter, seems it is reading entire file in one column and first column becomes index by default.

Comment: Try this: `pd.read_csv('File_name.csv', header = None, squeeze=True)`

Comment: Thanks @Vipin It worked. My final code was `y = pandas.Series.from_csv('File_name.csv', header = None, index_col = None)`

Comment: This question testifies how horibly stupid is pandas. I hate it. This action should be a trivial thing to do, and yet I need to search solution, which can't be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add index_col=None parameter, seems it is reading entire file in one column and default first column is treated as index.

Pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.from_csv.html) says Series.from_csv is discouraged. read_csv is much more powerful alternative you should use that.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 option read series from csv file;

1. `pd.Series.from_csv('File_name.csv')`
2. `pd.read_csv('File_name.csv', squeeze=True)`

My prefer is; using **squeeze=True** with `read_csv`